# Coldfusion ORM: delete in cascade

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I'm not an expert in coldfusion orm and I call your help because I'm pulling my hair!

I'm excepting to delete an entity 'Action' that has 2 relationship one-to-many, 'Texts' and 'Bonus'.

When I try to delete an Action that has only Texts but no Bonus, everything is fine. Hibernate deletes the Action record and the children Texts. It's what I want!

But when the Action has both Texts and Bonus, I got this error :

```
Column 'bonus_actionId' cannot be null
Root cause :java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'bonus_actionId' cannot be null
```

Why Hibernate does not delete the Bonus before deleting the Action ? Like it is done for Texts ?

Thanks

Action Entity:

```
component {
    property name="id"      column="action_id" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" generator="native";

    /* ... */

    property name="texts" type="array" 
             fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Text" fkcolumn="text_actionId" singularname="text"
             cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true";

    /* ... */

    property name="bonus" type="array" 
             fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Bonus" fkcolumn="bonus_actionId" singularname="bonus" 
             cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true";
}
```

Text Entity:

```
component {
    property name="id"      column="text_id" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" generator="native";

    /* ... (properties without relationships */

    property name="action" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="text_actionId" cfc="Action" notnull="false" lazy="true";
}
```

Bonus Entity:

```
component  {
    property name="id"      column="bonus_id" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" generator="native";

    /* ... (properties WITH relationships */

    // Parent
    property name="action" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="bonus_actionId" cfc="Action" notnull="true" lazy="true";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow Hiberate would first set the entity to Null (become orphan), then delete the orphans.

So.. remove `notnull="true"` from property `action` in Bonus.cfc and you're all set.

Comment: It is possible to keep notnull="true" and still enjoy to a automatic suppression ?
An bonus can not exist without an Action and I found the previous behavior useful.
I know that I can use the ORM events to handle the Action preDelete and manually delete all children but like it is "natural", I thought than it's implemented in Hibernate. It is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your `notnull="true"` and have cascades work correctly by adding `inverse="true"` to the foreign key–owning side of the relationship.

In your case, this would be on the `Action` entity:

```
component {

    property name="id"
             column="action_id"
             type="numeric"
             fieldtype="id"
             generator="native";

    /* ... */

    property name="texts"
             type="array" 
             fieldtype="one-to-many"
             cfc="Text"
             fkcolumn="text_actionId"
             singularname="text"
             cascade="all-delete-orphan"
             inverse="true"
             lazy="true";

    /* ... */

    property name="bonus"
             type="array" 
             fieldtype="one-to-many"
             cfc="Bonus"
             fkcolumn="bonus_actionId"
             singularname="bonus" 
             cascade="all-delete-orphan"
             inverse="true"
             lazy="true";
}
```

[Here's a write-up on how `inverse` works in Hibernate.](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/)